# Spring boot with spring security login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have simple web-application.I've used spring boot + hibernate + thymeleaf + spring security. I've made register system and it works correctly. I've tried to do login system, but I don't know if I understand spring security idea.
This is my securityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register","/","/home").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .usernameParameter("nickname")
            .passwordParameter("password").permitAll();
}
```

}

This is my login form:

```
    <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/login}"
      th:object="${user}" method="post" class="m-t" role="form"
      data-toggle="validator">


    <div class="form-group input-group has-feedback">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
      </span>

        <input name="nickname" type="text" th:field="*{nickname}"
               placeholder="Nickname" class="form-control" required />
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"
              aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
      </span>
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password"
               placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required />
        <span class="glyphicon"
              aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Zaloguj
    </button>
</form>
```

And I'm not sure if is it enough to make login system work?

Comment: Just one configuration that I dont see, you need to configure the authentication provider it could be for example an `inMemoryAuthentication` or `jdbcauthentication`

Comment: You can see a very good example at Spring official web site https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I would recommend using the standard `username` and `password` for the actual form field names. This will make it more likely that password managers and other helpers will understand your form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any authentication provider which you have to provide.

If you are using a Database, you will have to use the following:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

  auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
        "select username, password, enabled from user where username=?").passwordEncoder(encoder)
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
        "select user_username, role from user_roles where user_username=?");
}
```

If you are not using a Database or you want it for testing purposes, you can use the following:

```
 @Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

 auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ROLE_USER");
}
```